# How can I configure pg_hba.conf in kubernetes deployment when the ip address of client pods is not known?

Tags: kubernetes

Suppose I have two backends be1, be2 deployed in pods that use a postgres server in a pod, and I want to use `pg_hba.conf` to constrain access for better security, like:

```
hostssl db1  db1user    be1-headless.default.svc.cluster.local  md5
hostssl db2  db2user    be2-headless.default.svc.cluster.local  md5
```

I created headless services as well as clusterIP services for the backends, since a headless service has the IP of the pod - where the connection will come FROM.  Postgres reverse resolves the ip address for connections, and compares to the entries in pg_hba.conf.  Unfortunately while be1-headless.default.svc.cluster.local resolves to (say) 10.0.0.3, the correct ip address where be1 runs, 10.0.0.3 reverse resolves to 10-0-0-1.be1-headless.default.svc.cluster.local which doesn't match the pg_hba.conf.

Is there any way for a pod's ip address to be reverse resolvable to a DNS name that can be known in advance?  Another service we are using has a similar way of allowing connections (by ip or hostname filters).

---

I made a simple set of three resources to demonstrate this, sample-pod.yaml:

```yaml
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata: { name: echo, labels: { unique: "xxxx" } }
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: echo
          image: alpine:3.16
          command: ["sleep", "100000"]
    ---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata: { name: echo-service }
    spec:
      selector: { unique: "xxxx" }
      ports: [{ protocol: TCP, port: 8080 }]
    ---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata: { name: echo-headless }
    spec:
      clusterIP: None
      selector: { unique: "xxxx" }
      ports: [{ protocol: TCP, port: 8080 }]
```

```bash
    $ kubectl create ns myns
    namespace/myns created

    $ kubectl apply -n myns -f sample-pod.yaml
    pod/echo created
    service/echo-service created
    service/echo-headless created
    $ kubectl exec -it -n myns pods/echo -- ash
    / # nslookup echo-headless.myns.svc.cluster.local | tail -3
    Name:   echo-headless.myns.svc.cluster.local
    Address: 10.1.1.240

    / # nslookup 10.1.1.240 | tail -3
    240.1.1.10.in-addr.arpa name = 10-1-1-240.echo-headless.myns.svc.cluster.local
    240.1.1.10.in-addr.arpa name = 10-1-1-240.echo-service.myns.svc.cluster.local

    / # hostname -i
    10.1.1.240
```

The lookup and reverse resolution for the "echo-service" ClusterIP service works, but the ip address is a virtual endpoint for connections TO the "echo-service", not where connections would come from.

I'm currently mounting the predefined pg_hba.conf as a ConfigMap.  This is using Kubernetes 1.25, using Docker Desktop on a Mac in this example.  I thought a headless service would work since the docs say it is bound directly to the ip address of the pod.  But because the reverse resolution is not.